# Semicontinuous and monotone = Semicontinuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Is it true for a (upper/lower) semicontinuous function $f$ and a monotonically increasing function $g$ which is also (upper/lower) semicontinuous) that $f\circ g$ is also (upper/lower)semicontinuous?

Somehow I think that this is true( just a Feeling), but I don't know which equivalent definition of semicontinuity I can use to prove this?

Comment: Didn't you mean $g \circ f$?

Comment: Actually no, but if it is true for $g \circ f$, then this would be useful too. Can you give me a hint, how to prove it for $g \circ f$?

Comment: Hints: 1) for $f\circ g$ find counterexample when $f$ is continuous; 2) for $g \circ f$ apply $g$ to both sides of the inequality in the [definition of semicontinuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity)

Comment: regardubg 2.) let's assume lsc then f is lsc @$x_0$ if we have that $f(x)+\epsilon \ge f(x_0)$. applying $g$ we get $g(f(x)+\epsilon)  \ge g(f(x_0))$. What we want to have is $g(f(x)) + \epsilon \ge g(f(x_0))$, but this is true, since $g$ itself is lsc and this means $g(y) + \varepsilon \ge g(y + \epsilon)$, right?

Comment: @Lipschitz well, $g$ in general is not lsc

Comment: I assumed that $f,g$ have to be lsc. is it possible to get the result without this additional assumption?

Comment: It depends on what we want to prove. For lower semicontinuity of $g\circ f$ monotonicity of $g$ is sufficient. For lower semicontinuity of $f\circ g$ it is not.

Comment: I was going for $g\circ f$, since this was what Daniel Fischer recommended. Could you show me then, how this is sufficient? Probably this is the answer to my question, so I invite you to post it as an answer. Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim 1.** If $f$ and $g$ are lower semicontinuous and $g$ is monotone then $f\circ g$ can fail to be lower semicontinuous.

Indeed, take $f(x)=-x$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\le 0 \\ x+1 & x>0\end{cases}$. Then $f\circ g$ is not lower semicontinuous.

*Note.* In this example $f\circ g$ is however upper semicontinuous. But one can make $f\circ g$ worse by taking more complicated $f$, for instance $f(x)=\begin{cases}-x & x \le 1 \\ \sin\frac{1}{x-1} & x>1\end{cases}$.
In this case $f\circ g$ is neither lower nor upper semicontinuous. (Observe that the graph of $f\circ g$ is obtained from the graph of $f$ essentially by "cutting" away $(0,1]$ from $x$-axis...)

**Claim 2.** If $f$ and $g$ are lower semicontinuous and $g$ is monotone then $g\circ f$ is lower semicontinuous.

Let us fix $x_0$.

By lower semicontinuity of $g$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $g(f(x_0)-\delta) \ge g(f(x_0))$

Now, by lower semicontinuity of $f$ there exists $\gamma >0$ such that $f(x)\ge f(x_0) - \delta$ if $|x-x_0|<\gamma$. Using monotonicity of $g$ we get $g(f(x)) \ge g(f(x_0)- \delta)$. And using the inequality we obtained earlier we get $g(f(x)) \ge g(f(x_0))$, hence $g\circ f$ is lower semicontinuous.

*Note.* If $g$ is just monotone, Claim 2 does not hold. Just take any monotone not semicontinuous function $g$ and $f(x)=x$. (Sorry if my comments were confusing)

Comment: okay, thank you. then I agree with you.